# SQLite Database Get All Records NullPointerException

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

The SQLite Database works fine as far as add/remove a single row until I added the 
getAllRecords Method and have it run in Oncreate.

I've spent a lot of time fixing it, but no luck.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

MySQLite_Database:

```
    public static final String KEY_ID = "ROW_ID";                   // (0)
    public static final String KEY_ADD_REMOVE = "AddorRemove";      // (1)
    public static final String GROUP_POS = "Group_Position";        // (2)
    public static final String CHILD_POS = "Child_Position";        // (3)
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Group_Child_Pos_Table";
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_ADD_REMOVE, GROUP_POS, CHILD_POS};

    private static final String POSITION_CREATE_SQL =           
     "CREATE TABLE " + getDatabaseTable() + "("+ 
                                                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                                KEY_ADD_REMOVE + " TEXT," + 
                                                GROUP_POS+ " TEXT," + 
                                                CHILD_POS + " TEXT)";   

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    public MySQLite_Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CHILD_COUNT_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(POSITION_CREATE_SQL);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
//        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CHILD_COUNT_CREATE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + POSITION_CREATE_SQL);
        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);       
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
private MySQLite_Database MySQLITE_DATABASE;
private SQLiteDatabase  SQLite_database;
private Data_Holder_Class DATA_HOLDER_CLASS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list_view);             

    //Initialize variables here
    MySQLITE_DATABASE = new MySQLite_Database(this);


try {   

Open_SQLITE_DATABASE();
getAllRecords();
}       
catch (Exception e) 
{
   Log.e("ERROR", "ERROROR");
}


public void getAllRecords() {   
Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor != null)
    {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String GROUP_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GROUP_POS"));
        String CHILD_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_POS"));

        }
    }
```

}

Thank you very much

EDIT: posted the working code..

I finally found what I did wrong....

Here is the complete working code.  This may help someone else in the future.

BAD CODE:

```
    public void getAllRecords() {   
    Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null)
        {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            String GROUP_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GROUP_POS"));
            String CHILD_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_POS"));

            }
        }       
 }
```

to

GOOD CODE:

In MySQLite_Database:

I created this method:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableData() {
    SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return getWritableDatabase;
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
MySQLITE_DATABASE = new MySQLite_Database(this);

....

....

public void getAllRecords() {   
Cursor cursor = MySQLITE_DATABASE.getWritableData().query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor != null)
    {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String GROUP_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLite_Database.GROUP_POS));
        String CHILD_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLite_Database.CHILD_POS));

        }
    }
```

}

** Basically, in the BAD CODE, I had

```
private SQLiteDatabase SQLite_database
```

and used this for the cursor which was wrong. **  The cursor actually needs this instead

**SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();**

```
}
```

Thanks to everyone for helping, especially mmlooloo.
mmlooloo really helped me catch another mistakes.  I hope my mistakes helps someone else.

Comment: Which line specifically did you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: Does that mean the while condition?

Comment: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) and line 125 which is at Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null); inside public void getAllRecords() method. Thanks

Comment: post this line `MainActivity_ExpandableListView.java:125`

Comment: Trace SQLite_database variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change these lines:

```
 String GROUP_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GROUP_POS"));
 String CHILD_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CHILD_POS"));
```

to

```
String GROUP_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GROUP_POS));
String CHILD_POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CHILD_POS));
```

and

```
Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

to

```
Cursor cursor = MySQLite_Database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: good catch on these mmloolooo.  It won't let me change to just (GROUP_POS).  I changed it to (MySQLite_Database.GROUP_POS)... instead.  This also works: ....("Group_Position").  However, it only fixed part of the issues.  Another issue is also at Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null) I think.   It won't let me initialize the private SQLiteDatabase  SQLite_database anywhere.  I think this is the issue.  DO I need to initialize this?  If yes, how?   Thank you very much for your help.  I am so late for bed for work tomorrow!

Comment: Sorry it won't let me because it requires objects inside, but I don't have any objects.  I am still learning about the objects stuff too.  I have to go to bed.  Only 5 hours of sleep for work is not fun.  I can still check it at work when I get a chance,  Thanks a lot

Comment: post your `MainActivity` and `SQLite_Database_Helper` completely

Comment: I really appreciated for all your help.  Although it didn't help me catch everything, but most of it.   For someone else who has similiar issues, PLEASE CHECK OUT my working code above.   Thank you and thank you

Answer (score -2):

I think that you don't specify what columns you want int that line

> Cursor cursor = SQLite_database.query(MySQLite_Database.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

the function **query** needs:

> String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy

and in columns you put null, so you have to specify the columns you want

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I checked and checked....I still can't figure out what I did wrong.. I know it has to be the cursor section is doing that.